# TeamCity Import Project from one server to another with similar versions but not exactly the same

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I know that we can import projects from one TeamCity server to another only when the version number is the same. But I want to import projects from a server with version 9.0 to server with version 9.1.4. So is it possible that the projects can get imported as both version are 9.x?

Comment: Why not upgrade the first server with 9.0 to 9.1.4 first, then export? It's generally a good idea to have all your environments on the same version.

Comment: I would like to do that too, but that is not up to me in the organization I am working in. So would like to confirm if someone has exported/imported something like this before.